# mac yosemite: installing apache2 local web server giving forbidden or 403 status

Tags: apache, webserver, apache2, osx-yosemite

I am following [this](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11236) link to set up apache2 web server on my local machine.

I have successfully installed everything and got Syntax OK response but when I am trying to hit "http://localhost/~[your short user name]", I am getting 403 forbidden error.

I have kept [your short user name] as "Home" and as part of this, created new file: /etc/apache2/users/Home.conf and added following content:

```html
<Directory "/Users/Home/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require host localhost
</Directory>
```

Everything works fine, I get "It works!" on hitting "http://localhost/" but get forbidden error(403) on hitting "http://localhost/~Home". The error says "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /~Home on this server."

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEE6ZIonBoM&t=16s) and it's working now.

One change was in /etc/apache2/users/Home.conf file to:

```html
<Directory "/Users/Home/Sites/">

    AddLanguage en .en

    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted

</Directory>
```